# How to show persian date in rdlc report in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, date, rdlc, persian, persian-calendar

I have a  `rdlc` report in my application and i want to use a expression for showing Persian date,  but the problem is i can not find any expression for it, is there a way to show Persian date in my reports in `rdlc` file?

Comment: Maybe related: http://ilood.com/?i=ObwcXTETQTY=

Comment: thank you very much, it was very useful @NoChance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Report menu in rdlc report choose Report Properties, then go to "Code" tab and start writing a custom method for converting Georgian date to persian (Jalali) calendar in VB. (Remember in custom code you can only write codes in VB!) after that add a textbox in your report and write a expression like this: =Code.GetPersianDate(Fields!Date.Value)

which Date is a column in your dataset and obviously GetPersianDate is the name of the method.

thanks to  http://ilood.com/?i=ObwcXTETQTY=
it really helped.

Comment: Unfortunately, the above link does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Copy this code in Report properties/Code tab

```
Public Function   GetPersianDate(dtGeorgian as DateTime) as string
    dim  strPersianDate  as string
    dim  strYear as string
    dim strMonth as string
    dim strDay as string
    dim objPersiancal as System.Globalization.PersianCalendar
    objPersiancal = new System.Globalization.PersianCalendar()
    if(dtGeorgian =Nothing) then
    return string.empty
    end if

    strYear = objPersiancal.GetYear(dtGeorgian).ToString()
    strMonth = objPersiancal.GetMonth(dtGeorgian).ToString()
    strDay = objPersiancal.GetDayOfMonth(dtGeorgian).ToString()
    if (strDay.Length < 2) then strDay = "0" + strDay
    if (strMonth.Length < 2)  then strMonth = "0" + strMonth
    strPersianDate = strYear + "/" + strMonth + "/" + strDay
    return strPersianDate
End Function
```

now on any textbox you want right click and choose expression and add this Code in front of that expression.
`=Code.GetPersianDate()`

Note: your previous expression should be inside brackets.

Comment: This is work well `=Code.GetPersianDate(Globals!ExecutionTime)` , I don't use brackets, and I can't add any brackets without error.

Answer (score 2):

for  hour, minute and  second
you can add some lines to previous answers

```
    Public Function   GetPersianDateAndTime(dtGeorgian as DateTime) as string

    dim  strPersianDate  as string
    dim strPersianTime as string
    dim  strYear as string
    dim strMonth as string
    dim strDay as string
    dim strHour as string
    dim strMinute as string
    dim strSeconds as string

    dim objPersiancal as System.Globalization.PersianCalendar
    objPersiancal = new System.Globalization.PersianCalendar()

    if(dtGeorgian =Nothing) then

    return string.empty

    end if

    strYear = objPersiancal.GetYear(dtGeorgian).ToString()
    strMonth = objPersiancal.GetMonth(dtGeorgian).ToString()
    strDay = objPersiancal.GetDayOfMonth(dtGeorgian).ToString()
     strHour = objPersiancal.GetHour(dtGeorgian).ToString()
     strMinute  = objPersiancal.GetMinute(dtGeorgian).ToString()
     strSeconds = objPersiancal.GetDayOfMonth(dtGeorgian).ToString()
    if (strDay.Length< 2) then strDay = "0" + strDay
    if (strMonth.Length< 2)  then strMonth = "0" + strMonth
    strPersianDate = strYear + "/" + strMonth + "/" + strDay
    strPersianTime = strHour + ":" + strMinute + ":" + strSeconds

    return strPersianDate+"_"+strPersianTime


    End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I've found the problem. Second just show 18. My expression is `=Code.GetPersianDateAndTime(Globals!ExecutionTime)` and out put sample is `1401/04/17_17:32:18`